# Typed code exactly as in book, error being returned

Tags: c

As instructed by my text, created two separate .c files, that will be merged when compiled. But, one the files returns an error every time and therefore the merged file is never created.

I have run the programs in both Ubuntu and on an online C/C++ compiler and have reviewed the text probably 5 times. The code matches what is in the text in all cases and yet the error still appears.
Here is the code for the first file, called abs_func.c:

```
int absolute(int num)
{
    if (num < 0)
       return (-num);
    else
       return (num);
}
```

Here is the code for the second file, called abs_main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int absolute(int num);
int main()
{
    int x = -12, y;
    y = absolute(x);
    printf("The absolute value of %d is %d\n", x, y);
}
```

Then, I link by using:

gcc abs_main.c abs_func.c -o abs

I expect the file shown above to be merged with my other file (which apparently has zero errors) and to be able to open the new file, but that is not happening.
The error being returned is: /tmp/cc2EySTq.o: In function `main':
/home/main.c:15: undefined reference to`absolute'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Show the entire command lines you are using to compile and link.

Comment: Show the entire **command lines** you are using to compile and link. Those are the lines of text you type into the command shell to run the compiler and/or linker. They probably start with something like `cc` or `gcc`. If you are not using commands but are using a GUI (Graphic User Interface) to access the development environment (some IDE, an Integrated Development Environment), then say which.

Comment: This linker error is because `absolute` is declared, but not defined.

Comment: Does `int absolute(int num);` appear in the first file, with the semicolon? That source code will not compile. Remove the semicolon. If that semicolon is a typo from when you typed the text into the Stack Overflow editing field, then do not retype text. Always copy text and paste it into the field, to avoid typing errors.

Comment: This problem is not reproducible for me. With the text shown entered into files named as shown and the semicolon corrected, the command `gcc abs_main.c abs_func.c -o abs` compiles the sources, links, and produces an executable. Possibly, the contents of the files are not what you think they are, perhaps because you have not saved the buffers in the editor or because you have different files in different directories. In the window where you are typing the `gcc` command, type `cat abs_func.c` and cat `abs_main.c` to check the contents of the files.

Comment: Hm. Well I went and opened abs_func.c in emacs. Sure enough, there was a semicolon there. However, now that I have removed it, the compiler is giving me an error telling me that the semicolon is supposed to be there, before "else." I can't win.

Comment: You should have a semicolon at the end of `return (-num);` and before `else`. You should not have a semicolon after `int absolute(int num)` and before `{`.

Comment: Look.  Save all your files, close all your editors, and then figure out what is actually in the files, and update your question accordingly.  You're asking people to debug code that they can't see.

Comment: The code as it is listed in my question is now exactly how the book tells me to do it, and is how I typed it. And I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: “Listed in my question,” “how the book tells me to do it,” and “how I typed it” are fine. But none of those is “how the code actually is in the files.” You might have typed it one way, but something happened, and it did not get into the files or it got changed. That is why I instructed you to use `cat` to look at the contents of the files. If you type `cat abs_func.c` and `cat abs_main.c`, and then the contents of the files as shown by those commands exactly as shown in the question, then something is wrong we cannot diagnose remotely, and you will need to ask somebody near you for help.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I'll ask my professor who has traditionally never answered any other questions I have.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, your : gcc abs_main.c abs_func.c -o abs , is correct. But you are not typing : gcc abs_main.c abs_func.c -o abs , you typed : gcc main.c abs_func.c -o abs, that's why you get the message : /home/main.c:15: undefined reference to absolute.

Answer (score -2):

At first, the process of making an output from multiple object files is called *linking*, not merging.
This error is emmited from the linker program. I think you passed the file names out of order. As a rule, any reference to symbols that a file may need must be specified *after* it in the command line. In your case it must be as follow:

`ld main.o absolute.o`

`ld` is the linker command. You can use `gcc` for c objects or `g++` for c++ objects instead.

The `absolute.o` file must be specified *after* `main.o` because `main.o` needs a reference (`absolute`) that is defined in `absolute.o`.

And something else:
You must specify the `absolute` function in main.c as `extern`

```c
extern int absolute(int);
```

Comment: Linkers generally include **all** modules from any object module files they are given. It is libraries they selectively include from, so it is libraries that must be given after any files that use symbols from the library. Also, a plain `ld` does not know which language(s) the object modules were compiled for, so it does not know which libraries or runtime modules to link in.

Comment: I am using gcc to compile, not ld. And yes, I meant linking, not merging.

Comment: The statement “The `absolute.o` file must be specified after `main.o` because `main.o` needs a reference (`absolute`) that is defined in `absolute.o`.” is false. The linker will successfully resolve references in `main.o` to symbols in `absolute.o` regardless of the order in which they are specified on the command line.

Comment: The statement “You must specify the `absolute` function in main.c as `extern`” is false. Function declarations are `extern` by default. Per C 2018 6.2.2 5, “If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`. ”